# Get Response from Express File to Show in Other Javascript File?

Tags: javascript, function, express, post

So I am trying to add my `response.fee` value from my express file into another JS file that includes specific functions that update my front end app.

Here is the JS code I am trying to add the express response in. Is this possible?

```
import response from "express";

window.menuItems = 0;
window.tips = 0;

const tipTotal = document.getElementById("tip");
const orderTotal = document.getElementById("total");

document.addEventListener("click", ({ target }) => {    
  if (target.className === "food" && target.checked) {
    window.menuItems += parseInt(target.value);
  } else {
  return
  }

  tipTotal.textContent = `$${(window.tips / 100).toFixed(2)}`;

  orderTotal.textContent = `$${(
    Number(window.menuItems) +
    Number(window.tips) / 100
  ).toFixed(2)}`;

  console.log(response.fee); //I want to get this value from my express file
});
```

So I can update the orderTotal code to say this

```
 orderTotal.textContent = `$${(
        Number(window.menuItems) +
        Number(window.tips) + response.fee / 100
      ).toFixed(2)}`;
```

Is this something you can do with express? Or it's not possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure whether you're dealing with server-side rendering in your Express application or not but:

1. Assuming you're not doing SSR: you can make a request to your server (even if it's on the same machine - maybe your laptop or whatever) using `fetch` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch for more details).
2. However, if you're doing SSR you can start using something like `ejs` or `pug` and pass that value stored in `response.fee` to the `res.render` function in your Express app (`res.render(<FILE_TO_RENDER>, { /* object with values to be passed to the file */ }`).

Comment: I am already doing all of that in my express file. My problem is getting the response.fee value to display on my other JS file

Comment: `I am already doing all of that in my express file`
You mean you are already doing server-side rendering?